# How to modify my closure to add an error message

Tags: groovy

I have some code that validates a number of boolean rules against my input.

```
def validate(x, rules) {
    rules.each {
        if(!it(x))
            throw new Exception("${x} is not valid! Validation failed!")
    }
}

def rule1 = { y -> y > 10 }
def rule2 = { y -> y != 72 }
def rule3 = { y -> y < 100 }

def rules = [rule1, rule2, rule3]

def a = 12
validate(a, rules)
```

Each of my rules are closures containing a boolean expression.

I'd like to tweak my rules to contain an error message as well. Then inside validate I'd like it to throw the error message when the boolean evaluates to false.

Something like this:

```
if(!it(x))
   throw new Exception("${x} it(errorMsg)")
```

Since my rules are closures I'm not sure how can I do that? Can someone help me with how that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way (each *rule* is a map that has a validation closure and error message):

```
def validate(x, rules) {
    rules.each {
        if(!it.r(x))
            throw new Exception(it.e)
    }
}

def rule1 = [r: { it <= 10} , e:"rule 1 is not valid" ] 
def rule2 = [r: { it == 72} , e:"rule 2 is not valid" ]
def rule3 = [r: { it >= 100}, e:"rule 3 is not valid" ]

def rules = [rule1, rule2, rule3]

def a = 12
validate a, rules
```

Comment: This works as long as you don't want to mention the actual value in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as using Groovy truth:

```
def validate(x, rules) {
    rules.each {
        error = it x
        if(error)
            throw new Exception(error)
    }
}

def rule1 = { it > 10 ? false : "rule 1: '$it' is not valid" }
def rule2 = { it != 72 ? false : "rule 2: '$it' is not valid" }
def rule3 = { it < 100 ? false : "rule 3: '$it' is not valid" }

def rules = [rule1, rule2, rule3]

def a = 12
validate a, rules
```

and here another variant:

```
def validate(x, rules) {
    rules.each { r, e ->
        if(!r(x))
            throw new Exception(e(x))
    }
}

def rule1 = [{ it > 10 }, { "rule 1: '$it' is not valid" }]
def rule2 = [{ it != 72 }, { "rule 2: '$it' is not valid" }]
def rule3 = [{ it < 100 }, { "rule 3: '$it' is not valid" }]

def rules = [rule1, rule2, rule3]

def a = 12
validate a, rules
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the rules as keys in a map?

```
def validate(x, rules) {
    rules.each { rule, condition ->
        if(!condition(x))
            throw new Exception("${rule} is not valid! Validation failed!")
    }
}

def rules = [
    rule1 : { y -> y > 10 },
    rule2 : { y -> y != 72 },
    rule3 : { y -> y < 100 }
]

def a = 12
validate(a, rules)

validate 101, rules // java.lang.Exception: rule3 is not valid! Validation failed!
```